# How to get a value of an element by name instead of ID

Tags: jquery

How could I get the value of an element via the attribute `name` instead of the `ID`. eg if I use by id it would be `$('#id').val();`

Comment: what do you mean with 'name'?

Comment: But what do you mean with "name"?

Comment: I think he means <input id="ID" name="Name" type="text" />, i.e. using the name instead of the id field. But that may just be me paraphrasing with an example ;)

Comment: You can use any CSS selector there (at least I haven’t met an exception)

Answer (score 383, accepted):

Use the name attribute selector:

```
$("input[name=nameGoesHere]").val();
```

Comment: Also note that having the type of the element isn't necessary.

Comment: +1 for you Nick, because you were able to understand the question.

Comment: @thenduks: While this is true...name is usually found on inputs, and this does make the selector much faster.

Comment: just an update to this. The given method by @NickCraver didn't work for me, however $(":input[name=nameGoesHere]").val() worked in my case.

Comment: @Gunnrryy is correct, text fields work for me with $("input[name="xxxx"]") but returned a value of undefined on select elements, $(":input[name="xxxx"]") (adding : ) sorted the issue for me

Comment: If you want the value of the selected radio box use
$("input[name=nameGoesHere]:checked").val();

Answer (score 53):

```
$('[name=whatever]').val()
```

The jQuery [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeEquals#attributevalue) is your friend.

Answer (score 16):

Use the name attribute selector:

```
$("input[name='nameGoesHere']").val();
```

It is a mandatory requirement to include quotes around the value, see: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: I just wanted to note that in some cases (well at least mine), there is no need to put the 'input' part. The following will suffice ---> $("[name='nameGoesHere']").val();. Although, I am working inside of an Oracle package. I was looking at this post for reference and wasn't able to get it to work unless I removed 'input' from the statement. Just in case anyone else visits this post for reference and is also working with Oracle

Answer (score 8):

To get the value, we can use multiple attributes, one of them being the **name** attribute. E.g

```
$("input[name='nameOfElement']").val();
```

We can also use other attributes to get values

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="demoText" demo="textValue" />
```

**JS**

```
$("[demo='textValue']").val();
```

Answer (score 1):

This works fine .. here btnAddCat is button id

```
$('#btnAddCat').click(function(){
        var eventCategory=$("input[name=txtCategory]").val();
        alert(eventCategory);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//name directly given
<input type="text" name="MeetingDateFrom">
var meetingDateFrom = $("input[name=MeetingDateFrom]").val();

//Handle name array
<select multiple="multiple" name="Roles[]"></select>
 var selectedValues = $('select[name="Roles[]"] option:selected').map(function() {
    arr.push(this.value);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Only one thing more: when you´re using the "crasis variable assignment" you need to use double cotes too AND you do not need to use the "input" word!:

```
valInput  = $(`[name="${inputNameHere}"]`).val();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let startDate = $('[name=daterangepicker_start]').val();
alert(startDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

What element is used for the part with a green background? Just type the name of the element without "<" and ">" characters. For example type P, not `<P>` if the answer is the `<P>` element.

Answer (score -1):

you can also use the class name.

```
$(".yourclass").val();
```

Comment: Question is about getting value using name not class.