# read the html element with array name jquery

Tags: jquery, dom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get a value of an element by name instead of ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109472/how-to-get-a-value-of-an-element-by-name-instead-of-id)

How can I read the value of the field named `item[tags][]` from the following HTML document:

```
<ul id="mytags" class="tagit">
     <li class="tagit-choice">
       Acrylic
        <input type="hidden" name="item[tags][]" value="Acrylic" style="display: none;">
      </li>
     <li class="tagit-choice">
       Bath
     <input type="hidden" name="item[tags][]" value="Bath" style="display: none;">
     </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `hidden` fields are not rendered so you don't need `display: none`.

Comment: Also have a look at http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/ ... it's all there.

Comment: Also, *please* go and accept answers on all questions you've asked previously. Experienced users will be more willingly to answer your question plus it's useful for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use brackets to pass values as an array since `name` is not required to be unique across the page. Values with the same `name` attribute are passed on form submit as an array automatically.

I created an example filling JS array with elements values.

Markup:

```
<ul id="mytags" class="tagit">
     <li class="tagit-choice">
     Acrylic
     <input type="hidden" name="tags" value="Acrylic">
     </li>
     <li class="tagit-choice">
     Bath
     <input type="hidden" name="tags" value="Bath">
     </li>
</ul>
```

Code

```
var tags = new Array[];
$("#mytags").find("[name='tags']").each(
    function() {
        tags.push($(this).val());
    }
);
alert(tags.toString());
```

You can play with it: http://jsfiddle.net/VAjeN/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[name="item[tags][]"]').each(function (){
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this for getting value of a input with named 'something'. And you shouldnt use display none if you want to get its value

```
$('input[name=something]').val()
```